# ngIF with interpolation

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

guys a simple code for my understanding of how this directive work.
I have a ts file with two functions:

```
    chnageUserCreatedStatus()
      {
        this.userCreatedStatus = 'User is created';
      }
    
      NouserCreated(){
        this.userBorrado = 'User Borrado';
      }
```

and I have the html with:

```
    <h3>Users Components</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!allowNewUser" (click)="chnageUserCreatedStatus()">Add user</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="NouserCreated()">Borrar User</button>
    <div>{{userCreatedStatus}}</div>
    <div>{{userBorrado}}</div>
    <app-user></app-user>
    <app-user></app-user>
    <app-user></app-user>
```

you notice I have two interpolations but I want to created a condition to use only one interpolation and print either the function result chnageUserCreatedStatus() or NouserCreated()

I will appreciate any help

regards

Comment: If you're going to change the text that is stored at that property, you might as well just have one property and change the text and display it unconditionally. Otherwise, what's the point of having it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<h3>Users Components</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!allowNewUser" (click)="chnageUserCreatedStatus()">Add user</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="NouserCreated()">Borrar User</button>
<div *ngIf="showUserAdd">{{userCreatedStatus}}</div>
<div *ngIf="showBorar">{{userBorrado}}</div>
<app-user></app-user>
<app-user></app-user>
<app-user></app-user>
```

in ts file:

```
userCreatedStatus: any = "";
userBorrado: string = "";
allowNewUser: boolean = true;
showUserAdd: boolean = false;
showBorar: boolean = false;

chnageUserCreatedStatus() {
  this.showUserAdd = true;
  this.showBorar = false;
  this.userCreatedStatus = "User is created";
}

NouserCreated() {
  this.showUserAdd = false;
  this.showBorar = true;
  this.userBorrado = "User Borrado";
  this.allowNewUser = !this.allowNewUser;
}
```